# Steps to install preinstalled image

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, preinstallation

Ive downloaded Ubuntu Touch Arm64 preinstalled touch image (zesty) from website. I want to know how can I install the same on my android phone. Wot r the steps for the same, Im on YU Yunique Soc Qualcomm 410 chipset 4G fone.

-- Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Any genius out there who knows  how to DEPLOY these tar.gz files!?!

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for installing Ubuntu on phones are here

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

There are lists of devices that are supported and have community ports.  If your phone is not listed, see the link to 'Porting to a new device' at the top of the page.

Comment: What's the point for giving preinstalled images, when no one knows how to install them?

Comment: See the remark here https://askubuntu.com/questions/878085/can-ubuntu-phone-run-on-any-android-devices